# Offset foreach loop

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, paging

I want to implement simple paging.

I currently have a `Dictionary` and display its contents on a page by iterating through it with a `foreach` loop.
I could not find a way to offset a `foreach` loop.

Let's say I have 100 items. 5 items per page, which makes 20 pages in total. I'll start with the following:

```
int counter = 0;
int itemsPerPage = 5;
int totalPages = (items.Count - 1) / itemsPerPage + 1;
int currentPage = (int)Page.Request.QueryString("page"); //assume int parsing here
Dictionary<string, string> currentPageItems = new Dictionary<string, string>;

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in items) //items = All 100 items
{
    //---Offset needed here----
    currentPageItems.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    if (counter >= itemsPerPage)
        break;
    counter++;
}
```

This would be outputting the **first page** correctly - now how do I display the subsequent pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming first page = page 1:

```
var currentPageItems =
    items.Skip(itemsPerPage * (currentPage - 1)).Take(itemsPerPage)
    .ToDictionary(z => z.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Note that **technically** this isn't foolproof since, as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx states:

`For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue) structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.`

Thus it is *theoretically* possible for the same request for the first 10 items to return a different set of 10 items, even without any changes to the dictionary. In practical terms, this doesn't seem to occur. But don't expect any additions to the dictionary to be added to the last page, for example.

Comment: I liked your explanation and your `.ToDictionary` extension. Plus you need the reputation more than other people here :-)

Comment: @moontear - nice one, I like that you accepted the answer from the person with lowest reputation score. Great idea.

Answer (score 4):

With LINQ, you can use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to easily achieve paging.

```
var currentPageItems = items.Skip(itemsPerPage * currentPage).Take(itemsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the Linq [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)  extension methods ...

```
using System.Linq

...

var itemsInPage = items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage)
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in itemsInPage) 
{
    currentPageItems.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ's [`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx):

```
foreach(var item in items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to iterate over some elements just to get to some to the relevant index, it may be worth moving your items out of a dictionary and into something that is indexable, perhaps a `List<KeyValuePair>` (obviously creating the list will iterate through ALL elements of the dictionary, but can potentially do so only once).

This is then useable like so:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var list = dictionary.ToList();

var start = pageNumber*pageSize;
var end = Math.Min(list.Count, start + pageSize);
for (int index = start; index++; index < end)
{
    var keyValuePair = list[index];
}
```